# LWC test using jest testing framework throws error - unknown public property "smalldevicesize" of element

Tags: jestjs, lwc

While testing LWC in VSCode using jest script, unable to render custom LWC component, it throws an error- Unknown public property "smalldevicesize" of element . This is likely a typo on the corresponding attribute "smalldevicesize".

[Here is the error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDjtj.png)

Answer (score 3):

You are using a wrong attribute name **smalldevicesize** this should be **small-device-size**

Here is an example:

```
<lightning-layout-item small-device-size="">
```

Here is the Lightning Web Component  [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-layout-item/specification). I hope this should work.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me, I was srucked from long time

Comment: This solution worked for me while testing LWC custom component using jest testing framework.

Answer (score 1):

change the attribute to  because it supports to kebab notation.

Comment: Yes, jest UI support kebab notation for HTML template & jest.js supports camel notation for javascipt.